# Can I use novel as a basis for the plot of video game?

Tags: copyright

Let's say there's Hyperion Cantos, a novel by Dan Simmons. I'm planning to use that novel's plot as a basis for my video-game plot/script.

No character names or place names would be used (basically anything that could violate copyrights, etc).

Question is, how legal it is to re-use **ideas** from that novel in my video game?

(e.g. some fictional events/special abilities of a protagonist, basically everything that doesn't have name on it, but it has some properties/features that are related to original novel's fictional properties/features)

Comment: Even if you didn't copy character and place names, doesn't mean your story (based on someone else's) wouldn't be considered a derivative work (and thus could potentially run afoul of copyright law).

Comment: It would help if we knew the plot of the book.  Also, if we knew it's genre and your work's genre.

Comment: Hyperion Cantos is science fiction. If you use enough of the plot and similar characters, people may still recognize the source.

Comment: In the case of Hyperion the situation may be more complex as it follows a structure not unlike Chaucers "Canterbury Tales". Depending on how closely pavjel follows that structure it wouldbe possible to claim his work is derived from Chaucer rather than Simmons.

Comment: I would like to use the idea behind so called Farcaster (https://hyperioncantos.fandom.com/wiki/Farcaster), not just as it is, but rather wrapped using my video-game lore. I would ask that in my question, but I think that's too specific, so I had to ask something more generic.